# What is this small plastic air tube called?

Tags: part-identification, mazda-6

On my 2007 Mazda6 3.0L: I cracked the brittle plastic tube that taps into the main intake plenum, circled in red here below.  What is it called, and/or what is the replacement part number?

[image: Mystery air tube]

Comment: That should be part of the PCV system, as it attaches to the intake tract and down to the valve cover. I've looked for the line on the interwebz without luck, so don't have a part number for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a breather hose from the valve cover to the intake, 8561-01198867 might be the right part number for you.

https://www.partsgeek.com/gbproducts/WC/8561-01198867.html?utm_content=YN&utm_term=2003-2007+Mazda+6+Breather+Hose+Genuine+W0133-1853154+Front+03-07+Mazda+Breather+Hose+2006+2004&fp=pp&gbm=a&utm_source=google&utm_medium=ff&utm_campaign=PartsGeek+Google+Base&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrfSJ1p7Q3QIVwp6zCh0UBQgBEAQYBSABEgKY9vD_BwE&ad=47584901292

Comment: Nice find, that looks like it.